# using Object.keys for arrays of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use Object.keys to do some key assignation to my arrays of object. But it returned unique object for each iteration, so my 4 items became 2. Any way to avoid that?

```js
var cityIdmap = {};
var bpidmap = {
  '7': {
    cityid: 2,
    bpid: 7,
    name: 'Puduraya',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50169
  },
  '11': {
    cityid: 1,
    bpid: 11,
    name: 'Golden Mile Tower',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50172
  },
  '12': {
    cityid: 2,
    bpid: 12,
    name: 'Berjaya Times Square',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50171
  },
  '66': {
    cityid: 1,
    bpid: 66,
    name: 'Textile Centre',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50170
  }
};

Object.keys(bpidmap).forEach(function(item) {
  var bp = bpidmap[item];
  cityIdmap[bp.cityid] = {};
  cityIdmap[bp.cityid][bp.bpid] = bp;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(cityIdmap));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) that the object has already been initialized:

```
Object.keys(bpidmap).forEach(function(item) {
  var bp = bpidmap[item];
  if (typeof cityIdmap[bp.cityid] === 'undefined') cityIdmap[bp.cityid] = {};
  cityIdmap[bp.cityid][bp.bpid] = bp;
});
```

Comment: slick solution! but must we use typeof here?

Comment: @HarisZ Why not? What is confusing you?

Comment: @HarisZ: you can also use `if (!(bp.cityid in cityMap))` or just `if (!cityMap[bp.cityid])` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` in `cityIdmap[bp.cityid]` instead `object`

```
var cityIdmap = {};
var bpidmap = {
  '7': {
    cityid: 2,
    bpid: 7,
    name: 'Puduraya',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50169
  },
  '11': {
    cityid: 1,
    bpid: 11,
    name: 'Golden Mile Tower',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50172
  },
  '12': {
    cityid: 2,
    bpid: 12,
    name: 'Berjaya Times Square',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50171
  },
  '66': {
    cityid: 1,
    bpid: 66,
    name: 'Textile Centre',
    time: '+00:00',
    sbpid: 50170
  }
};

Object.keys(bpidmap).forEach(function(item) {
  var bp = bpidmap[item];
  cityIdmap[bp.cityid] = cityIdmap[bp.cityid] || []; //use array instead of object
  var temp = {};
  temp[bp.bpid] = bp;
  cityIdmap[bp.cityid].push(temp);
});
```